# Android: Can't able to load images from native "camera" album

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I can load images that came with the phone in the gallery. But when I try loading an image from the camera album(which is inside the same gallery), it doesn't show up.

But what's really weird is that it takes up space as if the image was successfully loaded. So it takes up space, but it's invisible. (Confirmed this by giving the ImageButton appears/visible.)

Code:

```
Intent galleryImagePick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                galleryImagePick.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryImagePick, GALLERY_IMAGE_ONE);
```

*Inside switch case*
ResultCode:

```
case GALLERY_IMAGE_ONE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri selectedImageOne = data.getData();
                imageViewOne.setImageURI(selectedImageOne);
                imageButtonOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();           
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
imageViewOne.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: It says "Unhandled exception java.io.FileNotFoundException, java.io.exception"

Comment: Can you change Intent for pick image like this please:
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 0x1;
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);

Comment: It's the same thing also I don't work. I got a clue that it's not working because the image size is very large. 
Seems like I have to compress the image size before showing them in ImageView. Now How should i compress the image size.?

Comment: If URI is finally not corrupted and you can get the Bitmap, you can compress Bitmap, and after that set Bitmap to image.
Compress method: 


//----------
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
Bitmap compressedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray()));
//----------

Comment: Hey @Gent I tried this code but still the Compressed Bitmap is larger in breadth.
    02-24 14:46:17.340 25276-25276/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too   large to be uploaded into a texture 
    (1944x2592, max=2048x2048)
02-24 14:46:17.442 25875-25875/? V/StateManager: destroy

Comment: int height = 512;
int width = 512; 
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, height, width, true);
//Dont forget -512 is in px

Try this and after that you can try to compress it?

Comment: It's working, but the problem is when I choose small images it gets resized to 512*512. How to automatically choose the scaling 512*512 for larger images which is out of limit size(2048*2048) not for small images which are already lesser than the limited size(2048*2048).

Comment: if(bitmap.getHeight()>=1028 && bitmap.getWidth()>=1028){
 //is above 512

int height = 1028; int width = 1028;
}else{
    //is below 512
int height = 512; int width = 512;

}

Comment: Still working on this, not getting the proper ratio of the image. I want to compress the image but don't want to loose the natural ratio of the image.

Comment: If you get the code to maintain the natural ratio of image please help me with that.